# XML Parsing Error while loading HarrCascade into CascadeClassifier

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I am new to openCV and copied some basic eye/face tracking code from [example code](https://github.com/ExpandingDev/OpenCV_Experiments/blob/master/FaceDetection/main.cpp). I receive a parsing error on line 20 - "face_cascade.load(...)".

```cpp
String face_cascade_name = "C:/Users/$Username$/Downloads/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";

if (!face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) )
    {
        cout << "--(!)Error loading eyes cascade\n";
        return -1;
    };
```

When I run it (in release mode), I get an "unhandled exception" and break. In debug mode, I also get an XML parsing error to the console (see below).

When debugging, I found everything runs as expected ONLY IF I use ["haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml"](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml) as my CascadeClassifier.

```cpp
String face_cascade_name = "C:/Users/$Username$/Downloads/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml"
```

I have tried re-downloading the HaarCascades multiple times from openCV's [github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades) (I don't see any other complaints about bad XML files). I have tried to load multiple different XML files, but all throw the same error, other than the "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml". I can't find this issue anywhere else I've looked online. I've tried re-building the openCV library, and even tried pasting the other classifier XML data into the header of "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml" and don't know what to try next.

Any ideas why only 1 HaarCascade XML file is loading correctly?

Visual Studio Windowed Error

```sh
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC5E3F9129 in testCV.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000883396DF90.
```

Debug Console Error

```sh
OpenCV(4.1.0-dev) Error: Parsing error (cv::XMLParser::parse) in C:\Users\$Username$\source\repos\testCV\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml(1): Valid XML should start with '<?xml ...?>', file C:\Users\$Username$\Downloads\opencv-master\modules\core\src\persistence_xml.cpp, line 786
```

persistance_xml.cpp line 774-786:

```cpp
    bool parse(char* ptr)
    {
        CV_Assert( fs != 0 );

        std::string key, key2, type_name;
        int tag_type = 0;
        bool ok = false;

        // CV_XML_INSIDE_TAG is used to prohibit leading comments
        ptr = skipSpaces( ptr, CV_XML_INSIDE_TAG );

        if( memcmp( ptr, "<?xml", 5 ) != 0 )  // FIXIT ptr[1..] - out of bounds read without check
            CV_PARSE_ERROR_CPP( "Valid XML should start with \'<?xml ...?>\'" );
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017, OpenCV 4.1.0, Win10.

Comment: Have you verified (debugging, inspection), that the XML file is correctly loaded? And, have you verified, that the XML file is valid? `Valid XML should start with '<?xml ...?>'` suggests (amongst others), that (a) no XML file was read correctly at all, or (b) that the XML file has an invalid format.

Comment: I tried copy/pasting a non-working file into the working one and saving - works. I guess there was a permission error somewhere. Still not sure where, but it's workable now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when copy/pasted the content of those xml files from GitHub to a local file. After cloning the repo locally, and coping the xml files to the desired place the parsing issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Clone "OpenCV" repository from github (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master)
on your local machine. "Dont" copy content .Copy paste file directly from cloned location to your visual studio. It would work.

Answer (score 0):

Here ,I finally find the true answer.

You need to change xml files to UTF-8.
Usually ,We download the file is UTF-8 With Bom.

You Can Change the File Code Using VsCode APP.(Please Google it)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).